# How to set image on center of svg circle?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have been created dynamic rotation in `svg`.

Here is my working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1oezxoa/

Now, may  i know, is there possible to set image in center of my rotating circle.

And may i know, what is the procedure to change the direction of text in each section?

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

My sample text align like this http://s1.postimg.org/if325n2yn/Untitled_2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can create a separate `<img>` that you position over the svg (using CSS' `z-index`, `position`, `left` and `top` properties)
Example: [jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/y1oezxoa/1](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/y1oezxoa/1)

2) I'm not sure if there's a better/faster way, but you can create animations for the `text`-nodes inside the triangles with a CSS transform that rotates the text 180 degrees at the top half of the circle, and rotates back at the bottom half. (Since you already know the timing of the spinning animation.)

Comment: I need to replace the red color circle to image @philip .. thanks ..If you explain in practical, it will better for me..

Comment: You can remove the red circle and place a <img> next to the <svg> inside a div-wrapper. See: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/y1oezxoa/1/

Comment: The animation-part is the same as you already made for the spinning wheel, but then for the <text> nodes.

Comment: yes, coding the animation for the text nodes is a bit more work, so that's something left to do

Comment: I need circle image, so i did <div class="circular1"></div> and css .circular1 {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
 } .. but it didn't work

Comment: If you want a full circle, use `border-radius: 50%;`. That should work with the rest of your code.

Comment: sorry @philip: hear is my jsfddle http://jsfiddle.net/y1oezxoa/2/ .. it doesn't work.

Comment: `http://link-to-your/image.jpg` should be a url to a real picture, otherwise the div will be empty.
For the positioning, use the css I wrote at the top (inside `wheel_wrapper > img`)

Comment: What that CSS does is put the overlapping element (img or div) to half of the width and height of the parent element (wrapper-div) and then pushes it back by half of its own width and height to center it.

Comment: it's in your last Fiddle (at the top of the CSS)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot. I just had to modify the values of the margins and that's it.